# Swift animation with constraint

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, core-animation

Is it possible to make a UIView animation by changing constraints?

Basically, I want to animate `myv` (UIView) which has x, y, height and width constraints, using: `UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5) {}` by changing the old constraints.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can do something like this:

```
func AnimateHeight() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
         self.heightCons.constant = 250 // Some value
         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()    
    })
}
```

Where `self.heightCons` is an `IBOutlet` to the height constraint on the `UIView`.

If you don't use storyboards you can check out [how to create layout constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651022/how-to-create-layout-constraints-programmatically).

For info on Core Animation and Auto layout: [Combining autolayout with core animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761622/combining-autolayout-with-core-animation)

Comment: I don't use StoryBoard I prefer doing everything programmatically !
So I should create a var for constraints ?

Comment: Yeah check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651022/how-to-create-layout-constraints-programmatically for how to do that.

Comment: What about Core animation can I Use CABasicAnimation with constraints ?

Comment: Seems like it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761622/combining-autolayout-with-core-animation

Comment: there is no answer :/ I want the same thing

Comment: I'd recommend searching around for core animation and auto layout. I found this: https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/auto-layout-and-core-animation-auto-layout-was/

Comment: @ramsserio, you asked "can I Use CABasicAnimation with constraints?" The answer to that is no. CABasicAnimation and other subclasses of CAAnimation all operate on layers, and constraints operate on views.

Comment: So even if the view has some constraints I can use CAAnimation to animate layers ?